# how can i deal with big mysql table with php for login authentication

Tags: php, mysql, database, codeigniter, optimization

I am working on a project using codeigniter framework.There are different types of users.Now we have 4 user types.I am using different registration table for every user like

registration_table_user_type1,

registration_table_user_type2,

registration_table_user_type3,

registration_table_user_type4.

But now i am using one login form with username and password input field.And i want to create a table for login authentication.This table will be like that

login_table(username,password,user_type,registration_id)

but i am worried about website.Because there will be more than 1000000 users for different type of user.How can i write mysql query for doing faster my website.I want some advice ,Please help me.

Comment: Hi do have you any idea about CRON

Comment: Google "database indexes"; though a different table for each user type is bad design

Comment: You could use only one `table` for users and an `column` with user type

Comment: Have a look into UNION queries. Because your data is split over 4 tables there is probably very little you can do (if you have your indices set correctly) that will speed up the data retrieval.

Comment: _“.I am using different registration table for every user”_ – and what justifies this decision?

Comment: why do you want to maintain different table for each user type? It's a bad practice, you should have one table with each row specifying user type. 

Ex. user_type(id, type_name) and user_account(id, type_id, username, password)

Comment: @Nes: How exactly does CRON help here?

Comment: @symcbean he has 1000000 records and that should not inserted at a single execution. So CRON is the best way to take the limit of records and add it in single table.

Comment: Splitting users across four tables is absolutely mind-boggling. You should have a core `users` table, a column designating what “group” they belong to, and a table for any group-specific data you join on.

Comment: @Nes: What has inserting got to do with the problem? Even if it were a question of populating the data, using cron does not help.

Comment: @CBroe because the structure of registration form is different for each type of user.And the registration table structure is different for every type of user.For this reason i have created a login table with username,password and usertype which values i am taking from registration tables.I want some better idea.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to try and normalise your database design first.  It seems strange to have 4 different tables which might have similar data (except for the type).  Typically one would have a table (USER) and in the table USER have a column representing either type itself or a foreign key to a TYPE table.

By using a single USER table, you then have the ability to leverage the database optimisation (indexing for one) and minimise the overhead.

Comment: Thank you very much for your advice.You are right.But i can't do it.Because the structure of registration table is different for each user type.I am storing different values from registration form for each usertype.I think you can understand what i want to do.

Comment: You could perhaps use sqlfiddle to better show the readers the current design and possibly a better design could be offerred

Answer (score 0):

Your database schema is not normalized, use this schema instead with innoDB engine

```
CREATE TABLE `user_group` (
`id` tinyint NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`label` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);

CREATE TABLE `user_account` (
`id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`gid` tinyint NOT NULL,
`username` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
`password` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
FOREIGN KEY (`gid`) REFERENCES user_group(`id`) ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE CASCADE
);
```

Comment: Thank you.It is helpful.From your answer i got some idea which is really helpful.But i am using a global login form for all user with 2 input fields like username and password.There are no field for choosing user type.I don't want to give any option for choosing usertype.there are so many users for each usertype.how can i write query for faster results?and the registration table structure is different for each usertype.Can you help me?I am not so good in database.I want to improve my database knowledge. How can i learn perfectly normalization.Please give me some tips.